# Apple voip notification expiration doesn't work

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit

I send voip notifications using curl to apns server. I use the following script:

```
curl -v \
 --header "apns-topic: **.voip" \
 --header "apns-priority: 10" \
 --header "apns-push-type: voip" \
 --header "apns-expiration: 0" \
 --cert-type P12 --cert *** \
 --data '{}' \
 --http2 \
 https://${APNS_HOST_NAME}/3/device/${DEVICE_TOKEN}
```

I disable wifi and cellular data for 1 min and send voip notication.
*apns-expiration* header works fine when APNS_HOST_NAME is api.sandbox.push.apple.com - I don't receive voip notification.
But when APNS_HOST_NAME is api.push.apple.com - I receive voip notification when I enable wifi back after 1 min, 1.5 min ...

I'm not sure what is wrong and what causes such difference in sandbox and production modes. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: As per apple official documentation you have to set two keys apns-priority: 10 and apns-expiration: 0 which you have already done it. it should work on production enviornment. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/

Comment: It seems like it keeps happening, any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the aps json block from the data payload

"aps": {
"alert": ""
}